# Give different Mocked responses for the same GQL query in component testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I am writing Unit Test for a scenario, where a GQL query will be called twice in a React component. I want my GQL query to return a mocked response for the first time, but an error on the second time for the same input. (In my case, my GQL query doesn't even take input). I have mocked the GQL response as such, but I'm not sure how to mock it for the second time call.

```
const mocks = [
  {
  request: {
        query: GQL_QUERY_1,
        variables: {
            id: 123
        }
    },
    result: {
        data: // SOME RESPONSE
    }
  },
  {
    request: {
          query: GQL_QUERY_2
      },
      result: {
          data: // SOME RESPONSE
      }
  }
];


  <TestWrapper>
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
      <MyComponent />
    </MockedProvider>
  </TestWrapper>
```

Is there any way, if I want GQL_QUERY_2 to give an error response if it is called second time in the component?